# Could not autowire sessionFactory in Spring MVC Test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

I want to write integration tests to our existing project written in Spring MVC. All of the current configurations are XML and I want to define separate config class with Java code to create DataSource and SessionFactory to use in-memory DB.

applicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="az.company.dcs.restapp"/>

<bean class="az.company.dcs.restapp.component.I18nConfig">
    <constructor-arg name="language" value="az"/>
    <constructor-arg name="country" value="AZ"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Configuration class I was created:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Profile("test")
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class TestDbConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("sa");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "sessionFactoryTest")
public SessionFactory sessionFactoryTest(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new 
LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    builder.addProperties(additionalProperties());
    builder.scanPackages("az.company.dcs.core.entity");
    return builder.buildSessionFactory();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory 
emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

private Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

    return properties;
}


}
```

my project structure:

[image]

But when I try to run my sample test it could not find my sessionFactory bean and gives error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 
'az.company.dcs.restapp.dao.AutoBraceletTrackingDAOImplTest': Unsatisfied 
dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean found for dependency [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sessionFactoryTest)}
```

My Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestDbConfig.class})
public class AutoBraceletTrackingDAOImplTest {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactoryTest")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void create() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Test");
}

}
```

Comment: You only active the configuration for the profile `test`. As you haven't activated the profile, your configuration is more or less ignored.

Comment: my bad. I thought that running test will automatically activate test profile. Thanks